# Grab data from table, join string from two columns, display in MVC selectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am new to MVC and LINQ.

I have a table with three columns (id, text1, text2).  What I want to do is generate a selectList in my view which has DataValue set to table.id, and DataText set to be = text1 + ", " + text2; (i.e. join text1 and text2 with comma separation).

What do you reckon is the best way to achieve this?

Cheers,

Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var v = dc.threecolumntable.Select(x => new {DataValue = x.id, DataText = x.text1 + ", " + x.text2 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I may have confused myself there.  By DataValue I think I meant "key", as in " SelectList(list, "Key", "Value", "SelectedValue"); ".  And I possibly don't understand this dropdown list properly.  So you have a relational table (id 1 = value x, id 2 = value y, etc).  You want a dropdown list which shows values x, y, etc; but when selected and passed to the controller POST method, goes to update the model (i.e. the other object/sql table) with the ID.  But in this case the text to display is the combination of the two strings...Just to confirm before I try your answer...

Comment: Well, inside the curly braces is what's known as an anonymous type, so you can name each property whatever you like.

You can change it to this instead - new {Key = x.id, Value = x.text1 + ", " + x.text2 }

Comment: Thanks, mate - I see where you're going with that.  I will mark you the answer.